# I can't understand Inverse Kinematics

Tags: animation, inverse-kinematics

So I am relatively new to Blender, and while figuring out the process that is rigging, and applying Inverse Kinematics to my armature, I came into contact with a weird problem, Normally, inverse Kinematics should look like this:
[image]

However, that's when I disable weight, which turns into a problem when animating, as weight should be on. This is what happens when I turn on weight:
[image]

I'm not sure what I did or what I'm not understanding, but it doesn't make any sense to me. Maybe someone with more experience could help me out?

So after I worked at it for a little bit, I got it to where most of the armature is normal, however, the lower leg is still broke, it turns into a thin like and is unable to function properly. Any help?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Community!  You appear to be using 2.79, I recommend using 2.8 going forward, as it is the canonical version from now on.  For a quick primer on bones and IK in 2.8, I recommend this video:  https://youtu.be/_uDnVHvlhEM

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out!

Comment: So upon downloading and installing Blender 2.80, I only encountered the same problem, upon adding weight to the IK constraint, the entire armature proceeds to turn into a straight, diagonal line.  Not sure what to do now, any help?

Comment: New edit on the main post

Answer (score 1):

I Can see that you are using the same pole target as you use as target. The pole target should be the bone in front of your knee as it controls the direction of the bending.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know what's going on exactly with your process, but I've followed this video myself and works just fine:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pt3-mHBCoQk

Hopefully this helps!